# Trying to implement threadpool but abort is being called

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool

I'm trying to implement a thread pool one producer, several consumers and my threads are constantly calling an abort exception before anything happens.

To implement this I'm using a mutex paired with a condition_variable that is intended to keep the threads waiting until notified by the main program thread that there is content that needs to be handled. I'm using c++11 in visual studio 2015. I'm pretty sure it's related to the wait mechanism since it only started to do that when I implemented it but I have no clue as to how to fix it.

```
//...

#define NUMBER_THREADS 8 //should be above 0
std::mutex nodelistaccessmutex;
std::condition_variable worktobedone;

//...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    //...

    //create threads for USE_LIST_THREAD and NUMBER_THREADS

    std::thread nodeForceCalculatorThreads[NUMBER_THREADS];
    std::stack<Node*> nodeStack;
    if (USE_LIST_THREAD) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_THREADS; i++) {
            nodeForceCalculatorThreads[i] = std::thread(threadPool, nodeStack);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 60; i > 0; i--){
        OrderedZListForceCalculationWithThreads(node_list, current - previous, nodeStack);
    }

    std::cout << "done" << current - begin << std::endl;

    if (USE_LIST_THREAD) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_THREADS; i++) {
            nodeForceCalculatorThreads[i].join();
        }
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

//...


//function that I think is causing the problem:

void threadPool(std::stack<Node*> nodeStack) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(nodelistaccessmutex);
    while (true) {
        nodelistaccessmutex.lock(); //lock or lock guard? notify one or all

        worktobedone.wait(lk, [nodeStack] {return nodeStack.empty();});
        std::cout << ".";

        //do actual work here
        //nodelistaccessmutex.unlock();

    }
    return;
}

//...

void OrderedZListForceCalculationWithThreads(std::list<Node*> node_list, double i_interval, std::stack<Node*> nodeStack) {
    //std::cout << ".";
    double x, y, z, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, distance, force;

    if (i_interval <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    for (auto& node_i : node_list) {
        nodeStack.push(node_i);
        worktobedone.notify_all();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found that if I comment out the 
nodelistaccessmutex.lock();

it runs though I'm pretty sure it needs to be locked before no?

Comment: Neither of those (the inner-loop lock and unlock) need be there in the code as posted.  the `.wait(...)` unlatches the mutex going into the wait, and the mutex is reacquired upon exiting the wait. If there is work to be done concurrently you can unlock the `lk` once it is acquired, and relock `lk` before swinging around to the  next while-iteration. Once you hand off  `nodelistaccessmutex` to `lk`, you shouldn't touch it directly again. And I also question whether that nodeStack should be a value-param. It sure looks like it should be a reference.

Comment: With the `unlock` commented out, your thread will just spin holding the mutex forever. Also, your calculation thread modifies `nodeStack` without holding the mutex that protects it. Fix those two things and make your threads in the pool pop something off the stack and it should work.

Comment: That fixed it @WhozCraig Thanks! (And yes, I changed it to a reference)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Isn't the wait supposed to unlock the lock?

Comment: @Kronephon Only while it's waiting. Say, for example, it doesn't have to wait because the stack is already empty. Then you'll spin forever and never release the lock.